# Como fazer multiplos uploads de imagens com Rails 3?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ruby, ruby-on-rails

Gerei um *scaffold* com o nome "property", preciso adicionar imagens junto a ele de preferência em um model diferente fazendo referencia (1 property pode ter muitas imagens), onde o usuário pode selecionar mais de uma imagem.

A idéia seria criar um botão de adicionar mais imagens e ter um preview antes de salva-las, com um botão de remove-la e um *radiobutton* para definir a qual vai ser a imagem de capa em cada preview.

É possível?

Comment: Não entendi, poderia explicar melhor?